# Graphics.Clear on a Windows Form Control also clears the control itself - how to prevent this?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, controls

I try to draw a custom selection rectangle on a Picturebox, using the method below:

```
    void _drag_UpdateView(bool clearOnly, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UpdateView");
        using (Graphics g = this.i_rendered.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            if (clearOnly)
                return;
            int px = (_drag_start.X > e.Location.X)?e.Location.X:_drag_start.X;
            int py = (_drag_start.Y > e.Location.Y)?e.Location.Y:_drag_start.Y;
            if (px < 0)
                px = 0;
            if (py < 0)
                py = 0;
            int wx = Math.Abs(e.Location.X-_drag_start.X);
            int wy = Math.Abs(e.Location.Y-_drag_start.Y);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, px, py, wx, wy);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I call:

```
g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

the whole picturebox turns black. However, the rectangle gets drawn over it.
If I do not call that method, the rectangles stack on itself, of course. I want to remove the old rectangle and create a new one like this.

Can anyone describe what's wrong?

Comment: Change your paint logic, do the drawing in the OnPaint/OnPaintBackground so you won't need to call Graphics.Clear

Comment: +1 Adriano, you should make that comment an answer. You rarely need to use "CreateGraphics" to draw controls.

Comment: @Adriano - Tried that now, but now the whole control turned white. [link](http://pastebin.com/sDwvJUYa) - I don't see the rectangle either.

Comment: @Tgys you do not need to use CreateGraphics if inside the Paint event handler, simply use e.Graphics.

Comment: @AndersForsgren I'm lazy and it's a short answer without any code or explanation, not enough for an answer!

Comment: @Adriano I did not use CreateGraphics. - I didn't remove the using statement yet. -------- Errr, that using statement caused it :P. Thanks for pointing me onto it. Now make it as an actual answer, since it IS the answer ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not paint your control inside any other method than `OnPaintBackground` or `OnPaint`.

Actually you may need it for performance reasons (your won't refresh the full control, just change something on-the-fly) but it'll make your code much more tricky and you'll always need to do the same job inside the `Paint` event too (because it may be called for many other reasons so the output should be the same).

Inside the `Paint` you do not even need to use `CreateGraphics`, the graphics context is inside the `PaintEventArgs` object so change your code to:

```
void DoPainting(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your calculations
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, px, py, wx, wy);
}
```

As pointed by @AndersForsgren to use the `CreateGraphics` method is not common and usually you do not need to call it (with the exception pointed before and when, for example, you need to perform some calculations based on the graphics like for AutoSize).